# Compute MAPE with negative actual values

Tags: regression, neural-networks, residuals, error, mape

I am training a residual data with negative values through ANN. So I partition my data with 20 values for testing. But what I get in my MAPE is a negative value. Here is my data:

```
ACTUAL        PREDICT           ABS ERROR      MAE
0.75580171    -0.007975448      0.763777158   1.010552303
-0.514778164   0.032106205      0.546884369  -1.06236901
-0.096233021  -0.010495104      0.085737917  -0.890940716
-0.397100416   0.028459884      0.4255603    -1.071669238
-0.445566292  -0.01842712       0.427139172  -0.958643371
-0.092824622   0.011291281      0.104115903  -1.121641017
0.293564335   -0.025122589      0.318686924   1.085577795
0.771313055    0.007514644      0.763798411   0.990257335
0.795749033    0.022372708      0.773376325   0.971884718
-0.92986609    0.003399248      0.933265338  -1.003655632
0.071147852    0.016120177      0.055027675   0.773427076
0.703022461   -0.033079848      0.736102309   1.047053757
-0.195794761   0.032912315      0.228707076  -1.168095992
-0.39405039   -0.049501059      0.344549331  -0.874378862
0.390061415   -0.027327846      0.417389261   1.070060366
-0.564169953  -0.045901939      0.518268014  -0.9186381
0.763752861    0.002061904      0.761690957   0.997300299
0.537237813   -0.02189205       0.559129863   1.040749273
0.523641566    0.003455477      0.520186089   0.993401064
-0.269772795   0.03695981       0.306732605  -1.137003474
                                         sum  -0.226771425
                                         mape -0.94%
```

My formula for ABS ERROR

```
abs(ACTUAL-PREDICT)
```

MAE

```
ABS ERROR/ACTUAL
```

MAPE

```
(sum/24)*100
```

Is that correct? Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

$ MAPE =\frac{100}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n |\frac{ACT_i - PRD_i}{ACT_i}| $

So you need to divide by $|ACT_i|$ and not $ACT_i$

Also, note that **MAPE** is quite unreliable especially when the actuals take values close to 0.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error

Comment: I used that equation last time but I got an 80% MAPE and it doesn't make sense cause the values are smaller and close to each other

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense? MAPE give you the mean percentage error, even if the error is small after dividing it by the actuals (which can also be small and close to 0) the percentage error might be a big number

Comment: The mean of your absolute errors is 0.479, this might seem to be a small value. But lets assume I predict 0 for all the records then the mean of my absolute errors is 0.475. Your model is giving you worse predictions than a 0 prediction.